# Кроссбраузерный тройной div

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Уважаемые разработчики, подскажите мне код кроссбраузерного дива, тоесть 3х дивов, которые будут отображаться в одной строке. Да, знаю, что есть в паблике все, но мне нужно немного другое. Нужно, чтобы все 3 дива были фиксированной длинны и не растягивались на всю страницу, а самое главное, чтобы тупой IE и FF читали его нормально. Помогите кто чем может.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

html

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="item">див1</div>
    <div class="item">див2</div>
    <div class="item">див3</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

стили

```
.clear{clear: both; height: 0; overflow:hidden; font-size: 0;}
.items{width: 600px;}
.item{float: left; width: 200px;}
```

Дивы будут в строку фиксированной ширины во всех браузерах

Comment: Спасибо!Помогло!

Answer (score 2):

так и задайте им ширину высоту через width,height. Чтобы были в строку используйте float:left

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD//XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" lang="ru">
<title>Ваша страница</title>
<!--
<style type="text/css">
   div {
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid green;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 5px;
    }
    #cleared_div {
        width: 625px;
        height: 50px;
        clear: left;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
</style>
-->
</head>
<body>
  <div>Первый раздел</div>
  <div>Второй раздел</div>
  <div>Третий раздел</div>
  <div id="cleared_div">Этот раздел нужен для избежания проблем с IE</div>
</body>
</html>
```

этот код работает в Mozilla Firefox 7, Chrome 13, Safari 5.0.5, Opera 11.51 и Internet Explorer 8

Зы: старался соблюсти большую наглядность, для этого рамки, поля, заданные размеры очищающего раздела...

Comment: Вы такой умный. Спасибо я не знал. Читайте тему КРОССБРАУЗЕРНЫЙ. Когда нормально в опере - не нормально в ие, и так далее.

Comment: а что в моём ответе Вам не нравится?я отлично понял суть Вашего вопроса.

Comment: Извините, все нормально. Я просто хочу сказать, что нужен кроссбраузерный див, который сделать, как вы говорите "задать ширину, высоту и флоат", не получается.

Comment: Ребят, а есть сайт типа tsya.ru, только с порядком слов в предложении? "А, то читать очень такие, сложно"

Comment: LeD4eG, тоже спасибО!